# Кастомный filter для querysets

Tags: python, django, django-orm, queryset

Добрый день, возникла следующая проблема:
есть модель, которая хранит изображения для галереи.

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='gallery/')
    status = models.BooleanField()
    type = models.BooleanField()
```

На странице эта модель используется для отображения в качестве галереи в виде плитки, masonry. Плитка фиксированная и проблема заключается в том, что необходимо взять 12 рандомных картинок, это несложно.

```
gallery = Gallery.objects.all().order_by('id','pk').order_by('?')[: 12];
```

Но вот чтобы у 5 из них тип был True, а у остальных 7 False. А если еще можно и кастомизировать порядок было бы вообще идеально, ну вот допустим, что у нас True - картинка горизонтальная(г), а False - вертикальная(в). Хотелось бы составить выборку, в которой будет, к примеру, такой порядок [в,г,г,г,в,в,в,г,г,в,в,в]

Comment: Лучше добавить в вопрос код модели и показать, что вы уже пытались сделать, чем выкладывать стену текста

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно, такой фильтрации сделать простым способом нельзя не то что на уровне Django ORM, но и на уровне СУБД. Я бы сделал такой список вручную.

```
qs = Gallery.objects.all().order_by('?')
return [qs.filter(is_horizontal=True).first()] + [qs.filter...] + ...
```

Кстати, `pk` - это просто псевдоним для `id`, если только у вас в модели нет полей с `primary_key=True`. Кроме того, последующий `.order_by()` затирает предыдущий.

Answer (score 0):

Если решать проблему "в лоб", можно взять 2 среза из объектов `queryset` и вывести их в шаблон

```
import itertools

q_all = Galery.objects.all().order_by('?')
q_true = q_all.filter(type=True)[:5]
q_false = q_all.filter(type=False)[:7]
galery = itertools.chain(q_true, q_false)
```

`itetools.chain` - объединит 2 кверисета в один, в указанном порядке
Что сделать рандомный порядок из генератора `galery`, нужно получить его значения и использовать `random.shuflle`

```
import random

galery_lst = list(galery)
random.shuffle(galery_lst)
```